# MEF import resolution

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, mef, dependency-management

Let's say that I have a class with a set of fields marked with `[Import]` attributes where all these fields prohibit [recomposition](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Recomposition).

At some moment this class is instantiated using `new MyClassWithInjectedFields(...)` and all the corresponding dependencies are injected using the `MEF` framework - nothing serious, only bijective `Export-To-Import` mapping.

> ### Questions:
>
> - Is it safe to assume that *in this case* the values of injected fields will **remain the same** until the class instance is garbage collected?
> - Or maybe there are some rare / obscure cases when they *might* get changed implicitly by `MEF` in runtime? Perhaps, when someone unloads or reloads the assembly used for dependency resolution?

*(I am new to `MEF` and I'm not really sure if there is a way affect the dependency graph in runtime, but, well, there obviously might be).*

Comment: If you don't specify explicitly that you allow recomposition, then if someone tries to change the catalog definition, for that export, an error/exception will be thrown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) MEF isn't doing anything special with the GC so the instances will not be GC'ed until there are no more live references to the objects.

2) If the Imports are not marked as recomposible then MEF will only ever change the values of Imports. You cannot unload\reload an assembly in a running .NET process, you can unload an AppDomain but in doing that you will essentially forcibly kill the object references but MEF doesn't do anything special to reset them.